# Does this sentence make sense? If not, how would you fix it?

Tags: grammar

Does this sentence make sense? If not, how would you fix it?

> The parents of families where the children are all grown up, their own parents are in their retirement years are faced with an ever increasing problem.

Comment: Sorry, but it's awful - not only ungrammatical, but unfathomable. Where did you find it?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence isn't grammatical because its structured to treat "where the children are all grown up" and "[where] their own parents are in their retirement years" as having the same antecedent, but they don't. The former refers to "families" and the latter refers to "parents of families", and then does so incorrectly using the tacit, repeated "where" followed by "their own parents" ("[where] their own parents") instead of the appropriate relative pronoun "whose" ("whose parents").

The length of the relative clause makes it easy to get lost, which is why I didn't even get as far as noticing that there *are* grammatical errors when I first wrote this answer. (Another contributor notified me in a comment, below.) I thought the wordiness was only causing an interpretation problem, and that's what I addressed here. [Now I'm editing my answer accordingly, to reflect the grammar problems.]

Anyway, to *understand* the sentence, think of it as "The parents of families (where the children are all grown up, and where the parents' own parents are in their retirement years) are faced with an ever increasing problem." Besides getting the two parts of the relative clause to refer to the same antecedent, I'd have used "and" instead of the comma, as the comma misled me into expecting the series to continue. This necessitates getting rid of "of families". Also, I'd put a hyphen between "ever" and "increasing".

> The parents whose children are all grown up and whose own parents are in their retirement years are faced with an ever-increasing problem.

I believe that takes care of the grammar problems, but let's work on the clarity. The opening word "parents" is redundant because, right away, we're mentioning their children. Further, "parents" is a bit confusing here because we're *also* talking about the parents of those parents. To *them* they aren't parents, they're children. Why single out their status, at the start of the sentence, as parents when the sentence is going to comment on them in that capacity only once and then move on to commenting on their status as someone else's children?

Finally, replacing the initial "parents" also allows us to remove "own" in "their own parents" because now we don't have to distinguish the reference to *their* parents from the reference to themselves as parents.

> People whose children are all grown up and whose parents are in their retirement years are faced with an ever-increasing problem.

It's possible, though, that even this could be cut down taking advantage of the availability of adjectives with the same meanings as two phrases:

> People with grown children and retired parents are faced with an ever-increasing problem.

That cuts out nearly half the words of the original and still says the same thing.

Finally, "are faced with" can be replaced by "face" here:

> People with grown children and retired parents face an ever-increasing problem.

Twelve words against the original twenty-six.

Comment: It's not fine; it's horribly ungrammatical, and as a result, it's difficult to understand how many generations are mentioned in the sentence, let alone determine what the subject of the sentence is.

Comment: Ah. On another reading, I do see one grammar problem: the incorrect shift in antecedent from families (where the children are all grown up) back to the parents *of* the families ([where] their own parents are in their retirement years).  That leads to another, because "[where] there" should then be "whose". I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: I think your final fixed version, "People with grown children and retired parents face an ever-increasing problem." is close to what I'm guessing the OP means. The only thing I would change with that would possibly be a word other than "increasing", perhaps "worsening" or a synonym. The problem itself isn't increasing, but perhaps the scope or the magnitude of the problem is increasing.

Comment: You're right. A problem isn't numerous, it's big. So "ever-growing" would be apt.